# Why don't I see the Pricebook2Id field as available in formula field on PricebookEntry?

Tags: formula, formula-field, pricebook, pricebookentry

I want to create a formula field on PriceBookEntry using the Pricebook2Id field, but it's not available, yet in the fields like it has it as a reference/lookup field. Product2Id is there. Any idea why or how I can get it?

Comment: This is good candidate for Idea exchange

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Pricebook2.Id` in your formula field on pricebookentry to return the related pricebook id.